# Image Segmentation- Selecting correct threshold

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am developing a brain tumor segmentation algorithm. Till now, I can correctly detect the tumor part of the image and then using thresholding segment them out.

For a tumor of light intensity, thresholding using mean, segment the tumor properly.

[image: Tumor1]     [image: segmented tumor]

But if the intensity of the tumor is dark, then thresholding using mean doesn't work (Since lighter pixels make the mean higher).

[image: tumor2]     [image: segmented tumor]

What method or code I should use so that One piece of code can successfully segment both types of tumors?

Comment: have a look at local adaptive segmentation algorithm, that should do what you want

Comment: @Trichoko tried some but not working for both tumor types.

Comment: Did you try with [edge](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/edge.html) function ? You should try playing with the threshold on the sobel method (or another).

Answer (score 1):

I worked on Glioma segmentation in my M. Sc.thesis, using a generative method with Expectation Maximization. My dataset consisted of 4 different modalities of : T1 Contract Enhanced MRI, T2 Weighted MRI, FLAIR, and PET scan.
The tumor appearance, regarding to its grade, could be a hyper intense, hypo intense or iso intense in different modalities.

The EM algorithm with 4 different classes of : WM, GM, CSF and Tumor, works well using the human brain atlas. 
Although it is always challenging to have a coregistered dataset which is aligned to the template, still this published method has been validated and it is highly accurate for different type of tumors in the brain.

The EM algorithm is implemented in 3DSlicer, as an EM-Segmenter, for different categories of Human brain, or Lung or ...

[image: EM segmenter with Atlas]

and here is the result of one test using slicer:

[image: tumor segmentation in slicer]

Answer (score 0):

graph cuts (or grabcut which is one of the methods which uses graph cuts) is a popular method for image segmentation,
 http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html

however you will need some way to generate seeds for foreground/background if you want to make it completely automatic.